# In Xamarin Forms, SetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-cloud-datastore

In `Xamarin Forms` with `.Net Standard` code sharing app, I want to set the environment variable for the `Google Datastore`. So that I can communicate with `Google Datastore` through the mobile app.

Below piece of code is working fine in `console` app but in `Xamarin Forms` throwing error while trying to create the Datastore db object.

**Error reading credential file from location /DB.json: Could not find file "/DB.json"
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**

I put the **DB.json** on the root of the solution.

```
try
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", @"DB.json");
            var dir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

            // Your Google Cloud Platform project ID.
            string projectId = "xamarin-project";

            //We are storing movies. So this is a Movie kind. 
            string kind = "Country";

            //Create the datastore db
            var db = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);

            // City entity
            Entity cityEntities = new Entity
            {
                Key = db.CreateKeyFactory(kind).CreateKey($"US"),
                ["CountryCode"] = "US",
                ["Name"] = "United States"
            };

            //Lets send the city to the datastore
            using (var transction = db.BeginTransaction())
            {
                transction.Upsert(cityEntities);
                transction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Read the file using `Dependency` is also not working. I tried with `.Android` project.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I think there is no such thing as environment variables on iOS and Android. At least not one that you can simply access or influence through your app

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the replay.

Comment: Are you trying to allow any user of your mobile app to access Cloud Datastore directly, or are there a limited number of database Admins that will use your app?

Comment: @JimMorrison I think app will be used in-house by the client, but I'm not sure right now. I'm very new to Google Cloud Platform. What if I allow any user to access? How can I do it in a secure way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use a database directly from your mobile app, I'd suggest you use Cloud Firestore (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/) instead.  It has explicit security features to allow accessing the database directly from clients.

I think what you are trying to do with the snippet above is to load your service account credentials in the app which will give any user of your full access to your database.